# Java thread pool to solve for a single result

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

Given a set of unequal input values (some inputs may be easier to solve than others), how to implement a multithreaded approach in finding a single answer (in one of the threads based on one "correct" input)

So for example, use multiple threads to find and return given letter in these arrays
(obviously with larger data sets in the actual program)

```
Inputs

[A, B, C, D, E, F]
[G, H]
[I, J, K]
[L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X, Y, Z]
```

Once the target element has been located, it needs to be returned from the thread to the calling function (parent thread) and all other threads can be killed

Things I have considered:

Using thread pools ('regular' Threads, Executor threads) to run and set the return value in the calling function (public variable?)

Cyclic barriers to block the main thread until an answer has been found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to do it all myself.  It provides better opportunities to screw things up, but also more flexiblity.  I'd start out with control fields:

```
public volatile boolean  foundIt = false;
public final boolean[]   jobList = { true, true, ..., true };
public final Object      threadLock = new Object();
public final Object      controllerLock = new Object();
```

(They should not really be public; give them the minimum visiblity you can get manage.)  Then start each thread, letting each know which array to search and which boolean it should turn off when done (`index`, below).  Pause the controller with:

```
synchronized (controllerLock)  { controllerLock.wait(); }
```

The Runnable in the threads should periodically check `foundIt` to be sure it is still false.  If true, it should shut down.  No synchronization is necessary.  When finding an answer, the search code should execute something like this:

```
haveAnswer:  {
    if (foundIt)  break haveAnswer;   // Already found by another thread.
    synchronized (threadLock)  {
        // Only one thread at a time can get into this block.
        if (foundIt)  break haveAnswer;   // Found since previous check.
        foundIt = true;
    }
    // Add code here to put answer in right place.
    // Only one thread will get this far.
}
```

When shutting down, whether hitting the end of the search array, noticing that `foundIt` is true, or finding an answer, finish with:

```
synchronized (controllerLock)  {
    jobList[index] = false;    // Tell world this thread is done.
    for (boolean active : jobList)
        if (active)
            // Another thread is still running.
            return;
    // This was the last thread. We're done. Restart controller.
    controllerLock.notifyAll();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set an AtomicReference with the answer which is shared and polled by the other tasks to see if they should stop. You can also use it to notify() the waiting thread.

```
final AtomicReference result = ...
// adds tasks
synchronized(result) {
    while(result.get() == null)
          result.wait();
}

// to check there is no answer. It doesn't have to be synchronized 
// as the value is thread safe.
while(result.get() == null) {


// in the task when a result is found.
synchronized(result) {
    result.set(answer);
    result.notifyAll();
}
```

I would use an ExecutorService.

Answer (score 0):

Add in the working threads a reference to the controller (who keeps a list of all the threads).

The controller has a method to signal that a result has been found, that method stores the result and kills/interrupts all the threads.

Comment: So something along the lines of having the controller keep a list of all the threads and, once an answer has been found in a child thread, store the value in the controller.  The controller is polling for that value to be updated (infinte thread.sleep - check loop?) and kills all child threads if it is updated?

Comment: It can be done that way too, but I am against polling if you can avoid it. Just make the controller have a method (let's say `valueFound()` and the thread that finds a solution calls it. Then, from this method, the controller kills all the remaining threads.

Comment: well, I need the calling method to return the "answer" value though

Comment: the program is structured so that someone calls findanswer() and that function (which is currently singlethreaded) will then spawn several threads to find the answer and return it

Answer (score 0):

Somehow, the threads that are looking for a result need to check that the result has been found.  They can do this by being interrupted and then checking the interrupted flag (any method that throws an InyerruptedExceprion does this check.

They can also check by looking at some other state like a result queue or Condition variable.

For example:

```
while (resultQueue.isEmpty()) {
    do a small amount of work
}
```

to check the interrupted state:

```
while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
    do a small amount of work
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ExecutorCompletionService to process results as they are found.
Once you get the result you want, cancel the remaining tasks.

What I like about this approach is that the tasks remain simple.  They just need to known how to do their work and detecting when they are canceled.

The creator of the tasks then handles processing results and determining when to cancel remaining work.